# Woocommerce rest api not updating order list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using woocommerce rest api version 2 and I'm having problem to list all order as its not giving me list of all recently added orders.

For example: If I had add one order which has order id :1922 so its added to backend but when I want to view orders using this api : wp-json/wc/v2/orders
it give me all orders except order which I had recently added which is 1922.

Its working charm till I have transferred server but after moving to other server it suddenly stopped working and due to that I'm having issue in my Ionic app in which I'm using Woocomerce v2 API.

What would be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by disabling static and dynamic cache and also cleared memcache too.

Its actually issue in server side above actions need to done and i disabled static and dynamic cache and also cleared memcache so it solve the issue.

So if anyone have such kind of issue please follow this step and issue will be resolved but if you have transfered site from one server to another then this solution will help.